# Special Character to Original string - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, character-encoding

I have tried the string(contain special character) to original String. The string received from service. I tried many codes. But i cant get the original String.

i tried the following code

```
// \U00e0\U00ae\U0089\U00e0\U00ae\U00b2\U00e0\U00ae\U0095\U00e0\U00ae\U00ae\U00e0\U00af\U008d

NSString *name2escaped = @"\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U0089\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U00b2\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U0095\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U00ae\\U00e0\\U00af\\U008d";
NSString *name2 = [NSString stringWithCString:[name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"name2 = %@", name2);
inputvalue.stringValue = name2;
NSLog (@"%@",name2);
```

Output prints:  à®à®²à®à®®à¯

I worked in Mac OS X development 10.9 Mavericks
Service sometimes send chinese character also. Can anybody help me

Comment: what should be ouput of this for example ???

Comment: Tamil Language or chinese or english

Comment: Change NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding to NSUTF16StringEncoding : Output is 屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰㠹屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰戲屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰㤵屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰慥屵〰攰屵〰慦屵〰㡤

Answer (score 1):

As according to your requirement `output` should be `Tamil or Chinese or English Language`

#### Change NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding to NSUTF16StringEncoding :

```
NSString *name2escaped = @"\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U0089\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U00b2\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U0095\\U00e0\\U00ae\\U00ae\\U00e0\\U00af\\U008d";
NSString *name2 = [NSString stringWithCString:[name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"name2 = %@", name2);
```

Output is : name2 = 屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰㠹屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰戲屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰㤵屵〰攰屵〰慥屵〰慥屵〰攰屵〰慦屵〰㡤 –

Comment: My string is = "C\U00d3MO REALIZAR LA CARGA NORMAL";
I want output = "CÓMO REALIZAR LA CARGA NORMAL";

Answer (score 0):

I did it 
My code is

```
- (NSString *) OrigninalString:(NSString *)getfilername
{
const char *c;
NSString *name2escaped = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",getfilername];
NSString *string = [NSString
                    stringWithCString:[name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                    encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
c = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
if (!c) {
    c = [name2escaped cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
}
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithCString:c encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
c = nil;
string = nil;
return newString;
}
```